# CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue") generates Run-time error '-2146232576 (80131700)': Automation error

Tags: excel, vba, createobject

This macro is supposed to count and delete duplicates displaying the number of duplicates to the right of the word

It stops at line `Set words = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")`.

> Run-time error '-2146232576 (80131700)': Automation error

There are a few macros I use that use this `CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")`. All work on my old computer but not on my new laptop.

```vb
Sub CountAndDeleteDupes()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim startCol As Integer
    startRow = Selection.Row
    startCol = Selection.Column

    Dim words As Object
    Set words = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
    Dim counts As Object
    Set counts = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")

    For Each cell In Selection
        j = 1
        count = 1
        If Not cell.Value = "" Then
            For i = j To Selection.Rows.count
                If UCase(cell.Value) = UCase(Cells(cell.Row + i,     cell.Column).Value) Then
                'If UCase(cell.Value) = UCase(cell.Offset(i).Value) Then
                    count = count + 1
                    Cells(cell.Row + i, cell.Column).Value = ""
                    'cell.Offset(i).Value = ""
                End If
            Next i
            counts.enqueue (count)
            words.enqueue (cell.Value)
        End If
        j = j + 1
        cell.Clear
    Next cell

    For i = 1 To words.count
        Cells(startRow + i - 1, startCol).Value = words.dequeue
        Cells(startRow + i - 1, startCol + 1).Value = counts.dequeue
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens, if you only write these 1 line in the code - `Dim words As Object: Set words = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")` and see what happens?

Comment: You may need to add mscorlib.dll to your references

Comment: System.Collections.Queue is a .NET type, 0x80131700 is CLR_E_SHIM_RUNTIMELOAD, "Failed to load the runtime".  Might happen when .NET v3.5 is not installed for example.

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant that was the issue. I don't know why I didn't think of that! Thank you.